# Merging a list of Strings using mkString vs foldRight

Tags: scala, functional-programming, string-concatenation

I am currently trying out things in Scala, trying to get accustomed to functional programming as well as leaning a new language again (it's been a while since last time).

Now given a list of strings if I want to merge them into one long string (e.g. `"scala", "is", "fun" => "scalaisfun"`) I figured one way to do it would be to do a `foldRight` and apply concatenation on the respective elements. Another way, admittedly much simpler, is to call `mkString`.

I checked on github but couldn't really find the source code for the respective functions (any help on that would be appreciated), so I am not sure how the functions are implemented. From the top of my head, I think the `mkString` is more flexible but it feels that there might be a `foldRight` in the implementation somewhere. Is there any truth to it?

Otherwise the scaladocs mention that `mkString` calls on `toString` for each respective element. Seeing that they are already strings to start with, that could be one negative point for `mkString`in this particular case. Any comments on the pros and cons of both methods, with respect to performance, simplicity/elegance etc?

Comment: Here is the source of mkString if you are interested. https://www.assembla.com/code/scala-eclipse-toolchain/git/nodes/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala?rev=9752caefeb97123f195b32b4166577e59bf22bce#ln262

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simple answer: use `mkString`.

`someString.toString` [returns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString%28%29) the same object.

`mkString` is implemented with a single `StringBuilder` and it creates only 1 new string. With `foldLeft` you'll create `N-1` new strings.

You could use `StringBuilder` in `foldLeft`, it will be as fast as `mkString`, but `mkString` is shorter:

```
strings.foldLeft(new StringBuilder){ (sb, s) => sb append s }.toString
strings.mkString // same result, at least the same speed
```

Comment: Same speed is not entirely correct in your example of foldLeft, using StringBuilder without the right initial capacity may end up creating more than one string depending on the input, not sure if mkstring iterates first to determine the right StringBuilder capacity but if that's the case then they are not the same speed otherwise then there is no guarantee that either will create only 1 new string.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `foldRight` unless you really need it, as it will overflow your stack for large collections (for some types of collections).  `foldLeft` or `fold` will work (does not store intermediate data on the stack), but will be slower and more awkward than `mkString`.  If the list is nonempty, `reduce` and `reduceLeft` will also work.

Answer (score 3):

Im memory serves, `mkString` uses a StringBuilder to build the String which is efficient.  You could accomplish the same thing using a Scala `StringBuilder` as the accumulator to `foldRight`, but why bother if `mkString` can already do all that good stuff for you.  Plus `mkString` gives you the added benefit of also including an optional delimiter.  You could do that in `foldRight` but it's already done for you with `mkString`