# Scala mkString equivalent in Scoobi Dlist

Tags: scala, scoobi

I am trying to use folds or better yet, `mkString` to concatenate the strings I have in a `DList`

```
val dlist = DList("a", "b", "c")
```

so that I get a single string : `"abc"`

Apparently, for a regular list in scala, `list.mkString` does the job.

[Merging a list of Strings using mkString vs foldRight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447681/merging-a-list-of-strings-using-mkstring-vs-foldright)

is there an easy way to do it in scoobi's Distributed Lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a method `DList.fold`:

```
/**Sum up the elements of this distributed list. */
def fold(implicit m: Monoid[A]): DObject[A] =
  reduceOption(R.semigroup) map (_ getOrElse m.zero)
```

Since the type `A` in your case is `String`, and scalaz provides an instance `Monoid[String]`, we can use `DList.fold`:

```
// make sure there's a Monoid[String] instance in scope
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val xs = DList("a","b","c")
xs.fold
```

Comment: i think there s no such method in a DList . see http://nicta.github.io/scoobi/api/SCOOBI-0.7.2/index.html#com.nicta.scoobi.core.DList

Comment: It wouldn't be on ``DList`` itself, but on a ``DList`` instance of the scalaz's ``Foldable`` typeclass. On closer inspection, I can't find such an instance -- sorry! However, looking at the API, there *is* a method ``fold`` which will do the same thing, as long as there's a ``Monoid`` instance for the type of ``DList`` you're trying to fold; ``String`` in this case. I'll update my answer accordingly.