# Most efficient way to turn a sequence of characters into a String (Scala/JVM)

Tags: string, scala, performance, functional-programming, jvm

Suppose I am composing a String from some linear `Char` data structure, e.g. a `List`, `Array`, or `Char`. What is the efficiency of each of these:

1. Compose a `Stream[Char]` in order and then append them together (i.e. using `foldLeft`)
2. Compose a String by **pre**pending each `Char` in order and then reverse
3. Compose a String by **ap**pending each `Char` in order

And is there another way of doing this that is more efficient than any of the methods enumerated above? (By "efficient," I'm referring to time complexity.)

I am particularly interested in answers pertaining to Scala, but answers relating to other JVM languages are also appreciated.

I would like to do this in as functional a manner as possible, i.e. without using even local mutable variables like `StringBuffer`

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/16447681/390708. `mkString` seems to be a good approach

Comment: @Brian as noted, I would like to avoid solutions that use `StringBuilder`, which `mkString` does use; but I'll take it if no better solutions are available

Comment: *(By "efficient," I'm referring to time complexity*. In that case, you won't be able to do better than O(n) since you have to access every character at least once

Comment: @jrook I understand that, but we could do a lot worse than O(n), e.g. if we traverse the String to the end each time to append a character

Comment: @ubadub, `mkString` achieves O(n). So you want a solution that is not `mkString` and has the same efficiency? May I ask why? A functional structure can also be optimized, i.e. use mutable data structures inside.

Comment: `String` stores characters in a mutable array internally, so does `StringBuffer` and the likes - if we drill down to the bottom, you can't possibly build a mutable array without building a mutable array.

Comment: Also, mutable state that doesn't escape function scope is perfectly fine with functional paradigm - that's why a lot of Scala collection transformation methods like `map` etc all use mutable state for performance reasons - but as an API user you don't even have to know about that because this mutable state doesn't lead to side effects

Comment: @Sergey I know, I'm just trying to see if there's a way to do without it. I'm operating by the general principle that mutable state should be avoided unless there is no other recourse. In my experience (as a relative beginner to FP) is that when I'm unable to come up with a solution on my own that doesn't use mutable state, it's due to a lack of familiarity with the FP "way" of doing things. Scala makes it easy to fall back on state as a crutch, so I'm purposely trying to learn to do things without using it.

Comment: Mutable internals maintain referential transparency. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: But constructing a java.lang.String *is* mutating state, like it or not. The only way around it is not constructing that String. Which could work if in reality you only need an immutable CharSequence.

Comment: @Ingo aren't java.lang.String instances immutable?

Comment: @ubadub Sure, once they're constructed. But the construction itself sets up a char array and fills it. Thus, the OP's task *will* have local mutable state (though hidden in the library).